# What kind of force comes into play when two molecules of a gas collide?

Tags: kinetic-theory

As per kinetic theory there is no force of attraction or repulsion between two molecules of a gas except when they collide. So, what is that force which is realized during collision with wall or another molecule?
Electrostatic/gravitational/nuclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classical mechanics interactions studied macroscopically, at the microscopic level of atoms and molecules on impact  are electromagnetic.

Gravity is a very weak force and assumes the strength we observe macroscopically through acting on a large number of molecules. On impact, where molecule meets molecule the small size of the [gravitational coupling](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/forces/funfor.html) makes any contribution irrelevant.

Atoms and molecules, though neutral have [spill over electrical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_force) and magnetic fields that give them a shape in space, attraction and repulsion regions. These, fitting like LEGO blocks create the solid state stability of matter. At the surface, these spill over fields will interact with the field of the incoming molecule or matter particles.

At the gas level, again it is the electric and magnetic  fields of the molecules that will interact. For the strong force to have an effect the energies must be much larger so as to penetrate the electron cloud that neutralizes the atom/molecule. Such energies can not be gained by neutral atoms/molecules. Ions and electrons can be accelerated to energies that will interact with the strong force, as happens in high energy acceleration experiments.